# Adobe Air multi-download

Tags: actionscript-3, urlstream

I have been searching both the web and stackoverflow for a complete answer to implementing multiple downloads of mp3 files downloadManager.  I have read a number of post and realize the most efficient facilities are to use ByteArray, URLStream and FileStream for saving t disk.  I have implemented as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
creationComplete="downloadFiles()">
<fx:Declarations>

</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.net.URLStream;
public var stream:URLStream;
public var fileData:ByteArray;
public var fileStream:FileStream;
public var file:File; 
public var trackString:String;
public var filearray:Array;
public var urlReq:URLRequest;

private function downloadFiles():void
{
filearray = new Array();
filearray[0]="Crazy";
filearray[1]="Distant Lover";
filearray[2]="Easy Going";
filearray[3]="Give In To Love";
filearray[4]="MuzicAgeErotic Moods";
filearray[5]="MuzicAgeGive In To Love";
filearray[6]="MuzicAgePieces Of Dreams";
filearray[7]="MuzicAgeThere will never be another you";
filearray[8]="Remembered";
filearray[9]="Teach Me Tonight"; 

downloadNextFile();
}
private function downloadNextFile():void{
trackString = filearray.shift();
urlReq = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8080/multiDownloadSampleApp7- debug/MuzicAge/"+trackString+".mp3");
stream = new URLStream();
file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("C:/Users/development/test/"+trackString+".mp3"); 
fileStream = new FileStream(); 
stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressBar); 
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeComplete); 
stream.load(urlReq); 

}

private function writeComplete(evt:Event):void
{     
fileData = new ByteArray();     
stream.readBytes(fileData,0,stream.bytesAvailable); 
fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE)     
fileStream.writeBytes(fileData,0,fileData.length);     
fileStream.close();         
stream.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressBar);     
stream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, writeComplete); 

downloadNextFile();
} 

private function progressBar(evt:ProgressEvent):void
{     
// progressBar 

}

]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Although it appears to capture and save all the MP3’s to disk I am constantly receiving the following error message.
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. at multiDownloadSampleApp7/downloadNextFile()[C:\Users\development\newgageProjects\multiDownloadSampleApp7\src\multiDownloadSampleApp7.mxml:40] at multiDownloadSampleApp7/writeComplete()[C:\Users\ development \newgageProjects\multiDownloadSampleApp7\src\multiDownloadSampleApp7.mxml:59]
[Unload SWF] multiDownloadSampleApp7.swf

When I close the error and look in the save directory I find all the MP3’s I requested in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're checking to see if you've finished downloading all the files before you call `downloadNextFile()`.

So the error is probably just that it gets to the end of the array and then tries to generate a URLRequest with a null string.

Comment: Cadin,  Thanks adding a function which tested if the array is empty worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!!!!!